# Repetition of two variables one after the other in Math.random()

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, ecmascript-6, background-color

I wrote the following code to randomly change the background color, but sometimes the two colors are repeated one after the other .... How do you think I can write the code so that the two colors are not repeated one after the other?

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "rgba(133,122,200)", "#f15025"];
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const color = document.querySelector(".color");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const randomNumber = getRandomNumber()
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
  color.textContent = colors[randomNumber]
})

function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
}
```

```html
<h2>background color : <span class="color">#f1f5f8</span></h2>
<button class="btn btn-hero" id="btn">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will happen because since it is completely random you might get the same number again.

You can put a while loop to ensure you are getting a new color every time. Keep a loop that keeps on running unless you get a new number.

Here `prevNumber` is used to keep track of the previous number. Now the code keeps on generating a new number until you have a different number from the previous one.

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "rgba(133,122,200)", "#f15025"];
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const color = document.querySelector(".color");
let prevNumber = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let randomNumber = getRandomNumber();
  while(randomNumber == prevNumber){
  randomNumber = getRandomNumber();
  }
  prevNumber = randomNumber;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
  color.textContent = colors[randomNumber]
})

function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
}
```

```html
<h2>background color : <span class="color">#f1f5f8</span></h2>
<button class="btn btn-hero" id="btn">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the last number generated. If that number comes back again, get another one.

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "rgba(133,122,200)", "#f15025"];
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const color = document.querySelector(".color");

let last = -1

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let randomNumber = getRandomIndex()
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
  color.textContent = colors[randomNumber]
})

function getRandomIndex() {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
  if (randomIndex === last) {
    return randomIndex = getRandomIndex()
  } else {
    last = randomIndex
    return randomIndex
  }

}
```

```html
<h2>background color : <span class="color">#f1f5f8</span></h2>
<button class="btn btn-hero" id="btn">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both current answers are totally ok. If you want to randomize just once you can do:

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "rgba(133,122,200)", "#f15025"];
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const color = document.querySelector(".color");
let currentColor = colors.pop();

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const randomNumber = getRandomNumber()
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
  color.textContent = colors[randomNumber]
})

function getRandomNumber() {
  const chosen = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
  const newColor = colors[chosen];
  colors.splice(chosen,1,currentColor);
  currentColor = newColor;
  return chosen;
}
```

```html
<h2>background color : <span class="color">#f1f5f8</span></h2>
<button class="btn btn-hero" id="btn">click me</button>
```

This way you prevent the current colour to be selected, and once the randomization has been done, you insert the one left out while removing the newly selected

Answer (score 0):

write `closure` like `noConsecutiveRandom` to get random number but not consecutively repeat.

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "rgba(133,122,200)", "#f15025"];
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const color = document.querySelector(".color");

function noConsecutiveRandom(size) {
  let last;
  return function rand() {
    const cur = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
    return cur === last ? rand() : (last = cur);
  };
}
const getRandomNumber = noConsecutiveRandom(colors.length);


btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const randomNumber = getRandomNumber()
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
  color.textContent = colors[randomNumber]
})
```

```html
<h2>background color : <span class="color">#f1f5f8</span></h2>
<button class="btn btn-hero" id="btn">click me</button>
```